# advance membership managment

Tags: login, membership

I have to develop user-login-account system for my web.
The web will have multi-level account access.
There will be a blog section (for non-restricted posts), forum  section, and  restricted (both post and forum) sections.
So I decided to create multi-level membership options.

- level I : basic account. Login on valid email.
- level II: restricted area account. Login on valid email and approved by admin.

Assumptions for my web:

- Everyone can read non-restricted posts. (no membership)
- Everyone needs to login to comment blog posts. (level I membership)
- Everyone needs to login to access (read) forum section and write forum posts.(level I membership)
- Some posts would be restricted only to level II membership.
- Only restricted users would have access to restricted content on web( some posts ) and some sections of the forum. (level II membership)
- Admin could suspend and remove any memberships for any user.

Could someone let me know how complex would be to develope this system and where to start. 
Any links/info/tutorials and help would be appriciated. 
Thank you for help.